# After pyinstaller code does not work as expected?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

[Code](https://github.com/ny4rlk0/BootcampManager/blob/main/BootcampManager.py)

This code works fine when it's .py. The second i use pyinstaller with this "pyinstaller.exe --one-file --windowed --icon=app.ico BootcampManager.py" acts weird and does not do what it normally do. It's stuck "Updating status". None of the buttons works.

Comment: Please edit the relevant code into the question. External links may break over time and make the question less useful for future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing `--onefile` with `--onedir`:

```
pyinstaller.exe --onedir --windowed --icon=app.ico BootcampManager.py
```

if that doesnt work, then try converting from `.py` to `.pyw` and get rid of `--windowed`

```
pyinstaller.exe --onedir --icon=app.ico BootcampManager.pyw
```

**EDIT**

from my experience with `pyinstaller`, when the exe is behaving `"weird"`, its because all the libraries (`DLLs`) are `statically linked` into the executable, that is what `--onefile` means.

when you link them `dynamically` (`--onedir`), they are imported at runtime or "when they are imported", so the executable doesnt need to load all the libraries after you open it. meaning that the executable will be `faster` and more `efficient`.

Comment: One directory partly works but then "window.after(2000,bootcamp_Status_Update)"
 spams cmd window in every 2 seconds.

Comment: Those who have same problem. The one worked in my case was "pyinstaller.exe --onedir --windowed --icon=app.ico BootcampManager.py".

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the direct answer for OPs issue. But I had the same issue in MacOS. In my case, I was trying to write a file in the same path as executable.

```
with open("myFile.txt", 'w') as f:
            f.write("Some texts")
```

This works when I run from code, but when I create the executable using `pyinstaller --onefile` and executes it, it extracs itself into home folder and try to run inside there, where it doesn't have write access. So it fails. I couldn't see an error log anywhere as well.

The solution was to use absolute paths.

```
with open("/Users/kmchmk/Documents/myProject/dist/myFile.txt", 'w') as f:
            f.write("Some texts")
```

This issue occured only in **MacOS** with `--onefile` option. I've tried Windows and Ubuntu and didn't have any issues.

Comment: You really shouldn't use absolute paths. Instead of that  import os and try assigning os.cwd() to a variable and use that. Modify it if it's neccesary. pathfile=os.cwd();myFilePath=os.path.join(pathfile,'myFile.txt') Now use myFilePath as variable inside of open without " .

Comment: @nyarlko, You are talking about "hardcoded paths" not absolute paths. when you use `os.getcwd()` you get an absolute path. I agree that we shouldn't use hardcoded paths.

Comment: Since i'm not a native english speaker it got lost in translation. I meant what you said.