# Wierd GUI behaviour with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I made a simple file organizer in Python with a GUI. When I run mu `app.py` with `conda` it works just as I intended it to, but when I run the executable that I made with `pyinstaller` it prints out the custom error message that I wrapped inside a try-catch block.

Here is the code in `app.py`, `organize_files()` is the brain of the script and `establish_current_dir()` is a simple function that uses `os.scandir()` and returns the files as a list of strings

```
from tkinter import *
import os
from ttkthemes import ThemedTk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox, ttk
from constants import *
from main import establish_current_dir, organize_files, TARGET_DIR_

BG_COLOR_ = "#252629" 

def browse_folder(folder_label: str):
    global target_folder
    target_folder = filedialog.askdirectory()
    folder_name = os.path.basename(target_folder)
    folder_label.config(text=f"Selected Folder: {folder_name}")

def organize_files_gui():
    if not target_folder:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please select a folder.")
        return

    files = establish_current_dir()
    organize_files(files)
    messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Files organized.")

def main():
    root = ThemedTk(theme="Adapta")
    root.title("File Organizer")
    
    root.geometry("400x200")
    root.configure(bg=BG_COLOR_)

    folder_label_frame = Frame(root) 
    folder_label_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=0) 
    
    folder_label = Label(folder_label_frame, text="Selected Folder: ")
    folder_label = Label(folder_label_frame, text="Selected Folder: ", foreground="#FFFFFF")
    folder_label.pack(side="top", anchor="center")
    
    made_by_label = Label(root, text="Made by Jakob™", fg = "#9d9ea3", bg = BG_COLOR_, font=("Helvetica", 32))
    made_by_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="center")
    
    style = ttk.Style()
    style.configure("Custom.TButton", foreground="#FFFFFF", background="#FFFDD0",
                    borderwidth=0, relief="groove")

    button_frame = Frame(root, bg= BG_COLOR_) 
    button_frame.pack(side="bottom")

    select_folder_button = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Select Folder", command=lambda: browse_folder(folder_label), style="Custom.TButton")
    select_folder_button.pack(side="left", padx=10, pady=20)

    organize_button = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Organize Files", command=organize_files_gui, style="Custom.TButton")
    organize_button.pack(side="right", padx=10, pady=20)
    
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    target_folder = ""
    main()
```

I am running MacOS and used `pyinstaller --onefile app.py` to build my executable. After reviewing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66385159/after-pyinstaller-code-does-not-work-as-expected) I used `pyinsatller --onedir app.py` since I was assuming there might be some errors with the library linkage, but it did in fact not work again.

Am I overlooking something in the process? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

```
#main.py
def establish_current_dir() -> List[str]:
    try:
        with os.scandir(TARGET_DIR_) as entries:
            files = [entry.name for entry in entries] # if entry.is_file()
            return files
        
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(ERROR_MSG_)   
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: There's no `try-catch` block in the code you posted.

Comment: What custom error? What `try-catch` block?

Comment: @Bramar It's in main.py and I'm importing it. Didn't want to paste the whole thing here so I figured it would just give a short description.

Comment: So, when you debug the error with a breakpoint or whatever, what is the actual file that is not found? We need basic debugging info here. Or just let the actual error message show, so that we can see the error from the `FileNotFoundException` which contains the offending path. I don't know why you'd use a custom error that has zero useful information in it. You haven't provided any actual specifics as to the particular problematic behavior, what the paths are, how you debugged this, etc, so please try to include more info here.

Comment: @Random Davis I don’t know how exactly I would debug the executable. I mentioned that upon running app.py (Python script) in VS Code the script works as intended (finds the file I select, and sorts the contents) but when I run the executable (app.exe) it says it can’t find the directory. I wouldn’t ask this question on here if it was just be some debugging matter. I do most of my work in C++, but since I am going into data science I figured I would start with Python (hence the custom error). I will dig deeper and try to find the source of the problem and let you know how it goes.